# How reduce the if conditions coding?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm not a coder but I'm editing a code based another stackoverflow user's code,

I'm trying to trigger an email every time the table is edited with respective name from the drop down list and then when the user tick the task as completed to trigger an another email, for some reason the table stops updating the google sheets backend when I keep adding more and more if conditions *(I don't know why).*

I have more than 50 user which need to added to the email trigger which is going to be a massive if conditions.

**Is there a way to reduce the if conditions and give it in a short way?**

[image]

```
    function editCell(props){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Data")
  const idCellMatched = ws.getRange("A2:A").createTextFinder(props.id).matchEntireCell(true).matchCase(true).findNext()

  const columnCellMatched = ws.getRange("1:1").createTextFinder(props.field).matchEntireCell(true).matchCase(true).findNext()

  if(idCellMatched === null) throw new Error("No Matching Record")
  if(columnCellMatched === null) throw new Error("Invalid Field")

  const recordRowNumber = idCellMatched.getRow()
  const recordColumnNumber = columnCellMatched.getColumn()
 
//Added new condition to send email
 const task = ws.getRange(recordRowNumber, recordColumnNumber-1).getValue()
 const comment= ws.getRange(recordRowNumber, recordColumnNumber-2).getValue()
 const body = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("A <b> new task </b> have been added to the Task Manager <br> <a href='https://sites.google.com/'>Visit Dashboard To Update</a>")
 const bodyCompleted = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("Task has been completed. <br> Comments - "+ comment+ "<br> <a href='https://sites.google.com/'>Visit Dashboard To Update</a>")
 
 
//----------------------------------Jonh Start
//Assign a name
if (props.val == "John") {
  GmailApp.sendEmail("john@abc.com", task, null, { name: "ABC",htmlBody: body.getContent() });
}
//click Task is completed
if (props.val == 1 ) {
  GmailApp.sendEmail("john@abc.com", ws.getRange(recordRowNumber, recordColumnNumber-5).getValue() + " Task is Completed", null, { name: "ABC",htmlBody: bodyCompleted.getContent() });
}

//----------------------------Peter Sart

//Assign a name
if (props.val == "Peter") {
  GmailApp.sendEmail("john@abc.com", task, null, { name: "ABC",htmlBody: body.getContent() });
}
//click Task is completed
if (props.val == 1 ) {
  GmailApp.sendEmail("Peter@abc.com", ws.getRange(recordRowNumber, recordColumnNumber-5).getValue() + " Task is Completed", null, { name: "ABC",htmlBody: bodyCompleted.getContent() });
}

//---------------------------Mark
//Assign a name
if (props.val == "Mark") {
  GmailApp.sendEmail("mark@abc.com", task, null, { name: "ABC",htmlBody: body.getContent() });
}
//click Task is completed
if (props.val == 1 ) {
  GmailApp.sendEmail("mark@abc.com", ws.getRange(recordRowNumber, recordColumnNumber-5).getValue() + " Task is Completed", null, { name: "ABC",htmlBody: bodyCompleted.getContent() });
}



}
```

Comment: That would send **a lot** of emails - if props.val is 1, that _if_ block will be executed for each user and thus send the email to everybody, not just the user ... maybe that's why your script stops working ? It trips some in-built spam protection and is killed ?

Comment: Kindly provide a minimal reproducible example: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) such as dummy sheets you're using so people can easily replicate your setup. Remove sensitive information if there's any.

Comment: The codes you have provided below are having errors which are unreplicable, If you can explain further or give screenshots of execution logs for errors you have, it would be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just put them in a map first and iterate thru ?

```
const users={Mark:'mark@abc.com',John:'john@abc.com'};
for( const user in users ){
 const mail=users[user];
 console.log('u:'+user+' m:'+mail); // <-- replace this with real code for an user
}
```

**EDIT:**
looking at your code - you don't even need to iterate as you are just searching for the right user and the map does that for you anyways -

I think you want to do

```
const userMails={Mark:'mark@abc.com',John:'john@abc.com'};
if( props.val == 1 ) {
  const completionUser = ws.getRange(recordRowNumber, recordColumnNumber-4).getValue();
  const completionMail = userMails[ completionUser ];
  GmailApp.sendEmail(completionMail , ws.getRange(recordRowNumber, recordColumnNumber-5).getValue() + " Task is Completed", null, { name: "ABC",htmlBody: bodyCompleted.getContent() });
} else {
  const assignUser = props.val;
  const assignMail = userMails[ assignUser ];
  GmailApp.sendEmail(assignMail , task, null, { name: "ABC",htmlBody: body.getContent() });
}
```

Comment: Sorry I couldn't understand this part of comment  `// <-- replace this with real code for an user` can you give me more details on how it should be done please.

Comment: simply replace that part with the _if_ blocks you had for each user, with _user_ where you would use the "John" and _mail_ where you used the "john@abc.com" example: `if (props.val == user ) { GmailApp.sendEmail( mail , task, null, { name: "ABC",htmlBody: body.getContent() }); }`

Comment: also, take a look at my comment up above - I don't think you want to make the `if (props.val == 1 )` for each user like this

Comment: I'm getting error message, I did everything as you instructed but there is no email triggering nor the data getting saved in the google sheets. :(

Comment: copy the error message - most probably it's just a typo by me or you ;-) ... did you replace the blocks with the user if-s were with my code fragment ?

Comment: @MBorik I'm little confused with many error messages (As I'm not a coder it making me spinning my head) this is my sheet can you please make a copy of this so that you can get a full picture of the task.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1t78q0Juz2ih0GNxpZ40tCCqQmXiQggD_7q8rnitjaYY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I think this is the error message : "Exception: Failed to send email: no recipient
    at editCell(dataServerSide:56:12)"